# What are the functions of Finger Follower, Lash Caps & Lash Disks and Seat Inserts?

Tags: engine

I have googled all teams, but do not understand well from the result

Finger Followers? (I see many website talk about rocker arms, but what is finger follower? Are they for different types of engine configuration?)

Lash Caps & Lash Disks?? (Are they put between the valve and rocker arm, but why are caps and disks? And how to hold them in place?)

Seat Inserts?? (I have no clue at all. I know what is seat for valve. Is "seat inserts" something between valve and seat?)

Pictures, websites and any sources are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular vehicle that these parts go on?

Comment: @Seminecis No. I am going to have an interview and those are keywords that I need to understand before the interview.

Answer (score 2):

A valve seat insert is a separate valve seat inserted into the cylinder head, rather than machining the seat directly into the aluminium of the head - this allows the seat itself to be hardened (or made of a harder material), and so to be more hardwearing and last longer.

'lash cap' and 'lash disc' are new terms to me, but appear to be US terms for different types of valve shim - these are used to adjust the clearances of the valves so that they open by the right amount. Discs are flat shims, and caps are top-hat shims used in certain types of engine to reduce weight. [(wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valve_shim)

[This site](http://www.autozine.org/technical_school/engine/vvt_5.html) and the wikipedia article on [Variable Valve Lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_valve_lift) Suggest that finger followers are used in Toyota engines to adjust the valve lift by changing the ratio between the cam lobes and the valves.

Comment: I see this youtube video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCB4-D9yITQ). It seems the "finger follower" has the same function as rocker arm, but it is directly hit by the camshaft. (Rocker arm is pushed by pushrod, and the pushrod is pushed by the camshaft). Am I right? Can anyone confirm it?